# Loading 'qdap' package failed in R

Tags: r, install.packages, qdap

I have gone through the threads related to qdap but their problem is not the same as mine. Moreover, many of them do not have accepted answers. I installed 'qdap' package but when I load it using `library(qdap)`, it returns the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’ in loadNamespace(i,
>   c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package
>   called ‘openNLPdata’

I have even tried `install.packages("qdap", dependencies = TRUE)` but that did not make any difference. Any information in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: Did you try installing openNLPdata by hand? i.e. ````install.packages("openNLPdata")````?

Comment: Try with `install.packages("openNLPdata")` and then `library(qdap)`

Comment: Yes tried that again and I still get the same error.

Comment: ... does openNLPdata successfully install and load for? If not then this really isn't an issue with qdap.

Comment: Just tried that and I get this error for openNLPdata:

Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\library" C:\Users\Dharam\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMDSPZh/downloaded_packages/openNLPdata_1.5.3-4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openNLPdata’ had non-zero exit status

The exit value should be zero for successful termination

Comment: Installing openNLPdata gives me this error: error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Comment: My R and Java are both 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem, too. I listed by solution as below.

First, you can try to install package(qdap) as this way.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("trinker/qdapDictionaries")
install_github("trinker/qdapRegex")
install_github("trinker/qdapTools")
install_github("trinker/qdap")
```

If "install_github("trinker/qdap")" is failed, you have to check the version of package "tm", which is "0.7.6". After updating this, you can install package "qdap" successfully.